# Will MacBook (Mid 2010) work with 1333MHz RAM instead of 1066MHz RAM?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I've a MacBook White (Mid 2010, 13-inch) with 2GB 1066MHz DDR3 RAM. I want to upgrade it to 4GB RAM. I'm looking for 1066MHz RAM in local stores but couldn't find one. Instead everywhere I can find the 1333MHz DDR3 RAM only. So before buying RAM, I want to be sure if 1333MHz RAM will work on my MB White without any troubling issues. So please give me an expert's advice. Will 1333MHz RAM work on my MB White Mid-2010 model? Or I'll just continue using my MB with 2GB RAM?

1066MHz RAM is not available in my city and making order from Amazon (or similar sites) is not possible for me as these websites do not provide services in my country.

My MB White (Mid 2010, 13-inch) specifications--

Processor- 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

Memory- 2 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

Graphics- NVIDIA GeForce 320M

OS- OS X Yosemite 10.10

Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is no issue with using faster-rated RAM as long as all the other specs of the RAM match what is required. It will run at the speed of the onboard memory controller.

Comment: for the record - you're wrong. This particular model has issues with faster ram.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-white-13-polycarbonate-unibody-mid-2010-specs.html this model support up to 16 GB RAM with Lion.  They have details and sellers.

If you also upgrade the harddisk to a SSD you will get a completely different machine.